# How can I project an object only if a specific field exists?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation, projection

I have the following documents in my MongoDB Aggregation stage:

```
_id: ObjectId('641316fd596514e63a2121ca'),
teamId: 5,
playerId: ObjectId('64131139596514e63a2121c1')
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('641316fd596514e63a2121ca'),
teamId: 5,
playerId: ObjectId('64143f7702ede13fea5ff3be')
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('64143f458b6a6cf54652d3a5'),
teamId: 17,
playerId: ObjectId('64143fa75a97b9a63a260e16')
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('64143f4f9ba5f2b3cf3030e6'),
teamId: 3
```

I want to create an Object field called **players**, and this object should contain the `playerId` and a `gender: 'male'`, but only if the document has a playerId property already. If not, it should just not do anything. So the result should look like this:

```
_id: ObjectId('641316fd596514e63a2121ca'),
teamId: 5,
players: {
    gender: 'male',
    playerId: ObjectId('64131139596514e63a2121c1')
}
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('641316fd596514e63a2121ca'),
teamId: 5,
players: {
    gender: 'male',
    playerId: ObjectId('64143f7702ede13fea5ff3be')
}
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('64143f458b6a6cf54652d3a5'),
teamId: 17,
players: {
    gender: 'male',
    playerId: ObjectId('64143fa75a97b9a63a260e16')
}
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('64143f4f9ba5f2b3cf3030e6'),
teamId: 3
```

I've tried to do this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      players: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $ne: [
              "$players",
              undefined
            ]
          },
          then: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$players",
              {
                "gender": "male"
              }
            ]
          },
          else: "$$REMOVE"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

But this adds an object even if there is no playerId property in the document.

Answer (score 2):

Works with `$cond` operator.

1. If the `playerId` field is not `undefined`, then set the `players` field with an object.
2. Else remove the `players` field with `$$REMOVE`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      teamId: 1,
      players: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $ne: [
              "$playerId",
              undefined
            ]
          },
          then: {
            "gender": "male",
            "playerId": "$playerId"
          },
          else: "$$REMOVE"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hTeNTE9-z1G)

Comment: Thank you this actually works great. However I was just giving some dummy data and the structure was not correct, so I apologize for my mistake. I've updated the OP with the correct structure and it still builds the object even though the playerId is not existing in the document.

Comment: No it does not work. The Database data structure you're starting with is wrong. Please check the OP..

Comment: Sorry about that, updated [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ckj8lwU5N7v). Please check. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, everything looks right and it works in the MongoDB playground, but when I do the same exact thing in the MongoDB compass it still populates the documents without **playerId**, so I'm very confused... The else key is greyed out, I so it doesn't remove the value..

Comment: This solution will **return** the correct answer. It will not **update** the document on the db. Do you want to update the db? If you want to update, use [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JoMmGB_ITqn)

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      players: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $ne: [
              "$playerId",
              undefined
            ]
          },
          then: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              {
                "playerId": "$playerId"
              },
              {
                "gender": "male"
              }
            ],
            
          },
          else: "$$REMOVE"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      playerId: {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$ne": [
              "$players",
              undefined
            ]
          },
          "$$REMOVE",
          "$playerId"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo at Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/og76mJJpdYG)